# How to call multiple functions within the code in haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to call multiple functions from within the code, meaning that by executing the .hs file, all functions named will be executed.

I tried using main with putStrLn, but this is rather complicated and doesn't seem to work.

```
main = do
 putStrLn (myFunction para1 para2)
 putStrLn (anotherFunction para1 para2)
```

This shows the idea, but it obviosly doesn't work. Escpecially because myFunction returns an Integer and not a char.

I hope someone can help. Thank you in advance.

using "print" solved this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Where are the multiple functions in your example? I see only `myFunction` (well, I also see `putStrLn`, but I assume that's not what you meant).

Comment: You don't _execute_ functions in Haskell. What's that even [supposed to mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_of_Louis_XVI)? What you do instead is, you _request & evaluate results_.

Comment: I think it's fair to assume that you are a beginner. If so then maybe you might find it useful to get used to Haskell using ghci, where you rarely need `putStrLn` to experiment

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please click the check box to accept it instead of editing your question to remark on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Escpecially because myFunction returns an Integer and not a char.

You can use `print` to print things other than strings. `print` is equivalent to `putStrLn . show`, so it can print any type that's showable, which `Integer` is.